# background image is not displayed correctly (centered) on iPhones

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, background-image

here is my css class

```
   .parallax {
         background: url(../images/indexParallax.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
         display: table;
         height: 100%;
         position: relative;
         width: 100%;
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
         overflow: hidden;
}
```

On desktop computers and android phones, this parallax is displayed properly. But when it comes to the iPhones (4 and 5 and 6) there is a problem. Image is displayed but is not properly scaled background image.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I believe `background-attachment: fixed` doesn't work on some versions of iOS

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself but here is a supposed solution

```
-webkit-background-size: 100%; 
-moz-background-size: 100%; 
-o-background-size: 100%; 
background-size: 100%; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;
```

Basically, if the browser cannot use the cover then it will resort to 100% which should provide a similar result.

`background-size: cover;` is [bugged](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) on iOS

Comment: Unforunately -webkit-background-size: 100%;  does not achieve same result as the -webkit-background-size: cover; This should be parallax, and when I set 100%, then it is just image which us not covering whole background